# Multiple weights per Edge in a JGraphT DAG

Tags: jgrapht

Is there a way in JGraphT that I can assign multiple weights to a single edge? For example, suppose I have a graph representing travel-time between cities. I want to assign edge-weights for "time by plane", "time by car", "time by bus", etc., and then find least-cost route by some specified mode of travel.

One approach I can think of is to have distinct graph for each travel mode and then add every city vertex to every graph but that seems like a messy and memory intensive solution.

My next thought was that I might be able to extend the class implementing the graph ( probably `DirectedWeightedPseudograph`) and customize the `getEdgeWeight()` method to take an additional argument specifying which weight value to use. That, however, would require extending all the algorithm classes as well (e.g., `DijkstraShortestPath`) which I am trying to avoid.

To get around that problem I considered the following:

1. Extend my Graph class by adding a method `setWeightMode(enum mode)`
2. customize the `getEdgeWeight()` method to use the currently assigned mode to determine which weight value to return to the caller.

On the plus side it would be 100% transparent to any existing analysis classes. On the negative side, it would not be thread-safe.

At this point I'm out of ideas. Can anyone suggest an approach that is scalable for large graphs, supports multi-threading, and minimizes the need to re-implement code already provided by JGraphT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a much easier solution: you want to use the [AsWeightedGraph](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org.jgrapht.core/org/jgrapht/graph/AsWeightedGraph.html) class. This is a wrapper class that allows you to create different weighted views of an underlying graph. From the class description:

> Provides a weighted view of a graph. The class stores edge weights internally. All getEdgeWeight calls are handled by this view; all other graph operations are propagated to the graph backing this view.
> This class can be used to make an unweighted graph weighted, to override the weights of a weighted graph, or to provide different weighted views of the same underlying graph. For instance, the edges of a graph representing a road network might have two weights associated with them: a travel time and a travel distance. Instead of creating two weighted graphs of the same network, one would simply create two weighted views of the same underlying graph.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about this class but it does solve the problem nicely. I did a quick test with a 150,000 node graph and saw no significant memory hit. As it turns out, prior to seeing your suggestion I had implemented my own wrapper class that pretty much does the same thing but w/o the function as constructor arg. A bit more flexible so I'll keep it as backup if AsWeightedClass can't handle something I need to support.